# Why must I put the command read into a subshell while using pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe, read, subshell

The command `df .` can show us which device we are on. For example,

```
me@ubuntu1804:~$ df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       61664044 8510340  49991644  15% /home
```

Now I want to get the string `/dev/sdb1`.

I tried like this but it didn't work: `df . | read a; read a b; echo "$a"`, this command gave me an empty output. But `df . | (read a; read a b; echo "$a")` will work as expected.

I'm kind of confused now.

I know that `(read a; read a b; echo "$a")` is a subshell, but I don't know why I have to make a subshell here. As my understanding, `x|y` will redirect the output of `x` to the input of `y`. Why `read a; read a b; echo $a` can't get the input but a subshell can?

Comment: Note that for the actual task you may prefer eg. `a=$(findmnt --noheadings --output SOURCE $(stat --printf=%m .))`, avoiding any parsing of command output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main problem here is grouping the commands correctly. Subshells are a secondary issue.

> `x|y` will redirect the output of `x` to the input of `y`

Yes, but `x | y; z` isn't going to redirect the output of `x` to both `y` and `z`.

In `df . | read a; read a b; echo "$a"`, the pipeline only connects `df .` and `read a`, the other commands have no connection to that pipeline. You have to group the `read`s together: `df . | { read a; read a b; }` or `df . | (read a; read a b)` for the pipeline to be connected to both of them.

However, now comes the subshell issue: commands in a pipeline are run in a subshell, so setting a variable in them doesn't affect the parent shell. So the `echo` command has to be in the same subshell as the `read`s. So: `df . | { read a; read a b; echo "$a"; }`.

Now whether you use `( ... )` or `{ ...; }` makes no particular difference here since the commands in a pipeline are run in subshells anyway.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use a [process substition](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```bsh
{ read header; read filesystem rest; } < <(df .)
echo "$filesystem"
```

The `<(...)` process substitution executes the contained script (in a subshell), but it acts like a filename, so you need the first `<` to redirect the contents (which is the output of the script) into the braced script. The grouped commands are executed in the current shel;.

It can be tricky to get this readable, but you can put any arbitrary whitespace into the braces and the process substitition.

```bsh
{
    read header
    read filesystem rest
} < <(
    df .
)
echo "$filesystem"
```

---

And it might be easier to use an external tool to extract the filesystem:

```bsh
filesystem=$( df . | awk 'NR == 2 {print $1}' )
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first command

```
df . | read a; read a b; echo "$a"
```

effectively gets interpreted as

```
( df . | read a ) ; read a b; echo "$a"
```

So the pipeline only feeds into the `read a` command.

Since you want multiple reads from the pipeline then you need to group the commands together.

Now it doesn't have to be a subshell; it could be a grouping..

```
bash-4.2$ df | { read a ; read a b ; echo $a ; }
devtmpfs
```

More commonly you might want a loop

```
bash-4.2$ df | while read a
> do
> read a b
> echo $a
> done
devtmpfs
tmpfs
/dev/vda3
/dev/vdb
```

There's a secondary issue with `bash` and the right side of a pipeline being run a subshell, so the `$a` `$b` values aren't accessible outside of the `while` loop, but that's a different problem!

Comment: The question is about extracting a filesystem name from the output of `df`.  Your “more common” solution extracts the first word from the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, 10th, …, lines.  That may be useful *sometimes,* but I don’t see how it’s relevant to this question.  I suggest that, if you’re going to present that loop construct, you explain what it does (you may copy my explanation from this comment) and demonstrate what it does; e.g., `ls -l | while read a; do read a b c d e f g h i; echo "$i"; done` outputs `file1` / `file3` /  `file5` / …